# Wlan interface went missing after reboot on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, iwlwifi

I installed Arch Linux today (5.17.1-arch1-1). During install and several hours afterwards I had no issues with wifi. After a reboot, there was no wlan interface any more.

```
-> ip link    
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e0:d5:5e:2e:6e:92 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e0:d5:5e:2e:6e:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

```
-> sudo rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
```

The hardware is still there (it's on the mainboard)

```
-> lspci
07:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
```

I also switched back to windows and could confirm that wifi is still working there.

I suspected a driver issue and found some silimar issues but nothing about the error message that I got:

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[    6.180161] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    6.217081] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:07:00.0 failed with error -110
[ 9817.475533] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:07:00.0 failed with error -110
```

I remember that I installed following packages during the last time, wifi worked:
base-devel, jre-openjdk and vulkan-tools.
Removing them did not helped.

Comment: Is the `linux-firmware` package installed?

Comment: Yes, it is installed.

Comment: is it dual-boot with Windows?

Comment: No. I installed Linux on a new, empty disc. I switched back to windows by plugging in the old windows disc, that I didn't formatted yet.

Comment: maybe try anyway to disable fast boot in bios (and then plug in this old win)

Comment: I disabled fastboot, booted into windows and back to linux, same error.